# `npm link` works even when I do not `npm link <package_name>` in the desired directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I read the npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) on npmjs.com for linking local packages and it says I need to do it in two steps:

1. Navigate to the local package dir and run `npm link`
2. Navigate to the package in which I intened to use this package and run `npm link <package_name>`

For example, if I want to use `packageB` as a dependency in `packageA`, I need to go to `packageB`'s directory, run `npm link`, then do a `npm link packageB` in `packageA`'s directory.

However, in practice, when I just to `npm link` in `packageB`'s directory and then `require('packageB')` inside `packageA`, it works, and any changes in `packageB` are instantly reflected in `packageA`.

Can anyone tell me how this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In fact when you do 'npm link', it create a link to you package globally on your system (you know it's something like when you do a "npm install -g xxx").

And when you require a package via Node it checks at many directory (the current node_modules, the parent ... & the global directory )

Comment: Understood, but then why the documentation states that doing `npm link <package_name>` in the destination directory is mandatory?